# type of visa for attending an academic conference in USA

Tags: visas, usa, india, conferences

I am invited to participate in a conference in USA that is happening from 16th March to 19th March of 2023.

I am an Indian citizen. As far as I know, I need to apply for B1/B2 visa for this. As per the present scenario it is almost impossible to get the visa in such short time of less than 2 months.

I heard there is J1 visa which may take less time than this.

Can some one who has done this successfully or who has sufficient information regarding this say how does one go about this.

Comment: There is an option. You can travel to Singapore and take the visa from there. Singapore US embassy allows visitors to take visa from there and wait times is very less there. Its very expensive option though.

Comment: @AnishSheela There is not enough time to do that I think..

Answer (score 5):

> I heard there is J1 visa which may take less time than this.

This doesn't sound like a scenario for a J1 visa. For J1 you need a sponsoring institution in the US to invite you and you'd be staying there for more than 3 days.

B1/B2 is the visa you need for a short hop for a conference.

Comment: I will be staying there from 15th to 20th (one day before and one day after the conference).. woudl that be sufficient? The institute is giving only partial funding..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik have you asked the institute whether they will sponsor you for the visa?

Comment: I have not asked specifically, but, I thought they would give some letter.. I got UK Visa and France/EUrope visa and the institutes sent some letters which was sufficient.. DO I need to ask them anything specific for USA?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik a letter would be sufficient for B1/B2 visa, for sure. For J1 - the sponsorship requires much more than a letter, it requires a job offer.

Comment: Littleadv: Not all J-1 programs involve employment.  But, @PraphullaKoushik, they do all require sponsorship not merely in the form of a letter but rather in the form of a DS-2019 form for participation in a recognized exchange program (see https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/exchange-visitors) which requires registering you in SEVIS for an additional cost of [$220](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/i901). "I got UK Visa and France/Europe visa and the institutes sent some letters which was sufficient": were those student visas or regular visitor visas?